# Not getting the phone number in android

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

I tried the following code it will display the "Name" but, doesn't display "Number".
Could someone please indicate where I have made a mistake?

```
package org.testcont;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Contacts;
import android.provider.Contacts.People;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class testcontActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView tvname;
    TextView tvnumber;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tvname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        tvnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

        Cursor c=getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
        while(c.moveToNext()){
        int name=c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME);
        String nm=c.getString(name);
        tvname.setText(nm);
        int number=c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NUMBER);
        String s=c.getString(number);

        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the older API, rather you should use this

```
android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
```

class to retrieve Contacts names and numbers also make the following changes:

```
Cursor c=getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
int name=c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
int number=c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.NUMBER);
```